# How to only send DTR/RTS signal on port open but not port close via pySerial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have a system which, when its COM port is opened or closed via pySerial, receives reset signals on both which is nominal behavior:

```
with Serial("COM4", 19200) as ser:
    ser.write(bytearray[89])
```

What I want to have happen however is for the reset to only occur on port open, and to allow the system to continue running on port close.

My unsuccessful attempt:

```
ser = serial_for_url("COM4", 19200, do_not_open=True)
ser.dtr = 0
ser.rts = 0
ser.open()

ser.write(bytearray[89])

ser.dtr = 1
ser.rts = 1
ser.close()
```

Is this possible? Or are the nature of posix ports such that their behavior is fixed at instantiation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not they can be done depends on the operating system and device drivers.
Then, the setting value of `rts`,`dtr` will be `True`,`False` instead of `1`,`0`.

[pySerial API](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html)

> `open()`
>   Open port. The state of `rts` and `dtr` is applied.
>
> > Some OS and/or drivers may activate RTS and or DTR automatically, as soon as the port is opened.
> >     There may be a glitch on RTS/DTR when `rts` or `dtr` are set differently from their default value (`True` / active).
> >
> > For compatibility reasons, no error is reported when applying `rts` or `dtr` fails on POSIX due to EINVAL (22) or ENOTTY (25).
>
> `rts`
>   **Setter:** Set the state of the RTS line
>   **Getter:** Return the state of the RTS line
>   **Type:** bool
>
> Set RTS line to specified logic level. It is possible to assign this value before opening the serial port, then the value is applied upon `open()` (with restrictions, see `open()`).
>
> `dtr`
>   **Setter:** Set the state of the DTR line
>   **Getter:** Return the state of the DTR line
>   **Type:** bool
>
> Set DTR line to specified logic level. It is possible to assign this value before opening the serial port, then the value is applied upon `open()` (with restrictions, see `open()`).

---

If your system supports the features, could your program be modified as follows?
Please try it.

```
ser = serial_for_url("COM4", 19200, do_not_open=True)
ser.dtr = False
ser.rts = False
ser.open()
time.sleep(0.1) # The time required for the device to recognize the reset condition.
ser.dtr = True
ser.rts = True
time.sleep(2.0) # The time required for the device to complete the reset operation.

ser.write(bytearray[89])

ser.flush() # wait until all data is written.
ser.close()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I see absolutely no change in the pin state.

Comment: For example, try it with something other than Python such as C. If that doesn't work, it's probably an OS or driver problem.